# Автоматическое закрытие панели с меню

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Добрый день) Есть на экране 2 фрагмента(выезжающее боковое меню и фрагмент с другой информацией). Подскажите, как лучше сделать автоматическое закрытие панели с меню, когда пользователь нажимает на любой элемент на другом фрагменте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать [нативное решение от гугла](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)? Там можно прямо вызвать метод "закрытия" (убирания) выезжающего бокового меню.

Comment: Уже используем SlidingPaneLayout